# STTCL FSM framework based on the GoF State Pattern, Part I: The basic interfaces

Tags: c++, design-patterns, library, state-machine, framework

## Preface

I have decided to let my pet project created some years ago to undergo a code review here.

The review will be broken into parts according to meta question [Multiple reviews or one big review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/multiple-reviews-or-one-big-review).

The overall concept and motivation can be inspected [here](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/docs/STTCL-Concept.pdf) (be patient, it takes some time to load).

The doxygen generated documentation can be accessed online [here](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/docs/html/index.html) (it loads a bit quicker).

---

## The basic idea

The GoF design pattern catalogue proposes the [State Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) which can merely boiled down that the `State` provides a specific interface that is delegate called by the `StateMachine`'s public functions to a current concrete `State` implementation.

Now according to the UML notation there are specific standardized methods that apply for a `State` like `enter()`, `exit()` or `do()`. The other internal interface methods are context and application specific, and have to be implemented for a concrete implementation.

The goal of STTCL is to make it easier to create `StateMachine` implementations translating from UML StateMachine diagrams. Something like this:

[image]

```
                                           |     |
                                           |     |
                                           |     |
                                          \       /
                                           \     /
                                            \   /
                                             \ /
                                              V
```

[image]

Any kind of critique and annotation is appreciated. All the test cases and demos are running fine and as intended BTW.

## Part I: Core classes and basic interfaces

[image]

[**StateMachine.h**](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/blob/master/sttcl/include/StateMachine.h)

```
/* license header omitted */
#ifndef STATEMACHINE_H_
#define STATEMACHINE_H_

#include "SttclConfig.h"

#include "State.h"
#include <cassert>
#if defined(STTCL_DEBUG)
#include <iostream>
#if defined(STTCL_HAVE_RTTI)
#include <typeinfo>
#endif
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_USE_STL)
#include <set>
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
#include "SttclMutex.h"
#endif

namespace sttcl
{

/**
 * State machine flags bitfield.
 */
struct StateMachineFlags
{
    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is initialized.
     */
    unsigned char initialized:1;
    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is currently initializing.
     */
    unsigned char initializing:1;
    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is finalized.
     */
    unsigned char finalized:1;
    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is currently finalizing.
     */
    unsigned char finalizing:1;


    inline StateMachineFlags(const StateMachineFlags& rhs)
    : initialized(rhs.initialized)
    , initializing(rhs.initializing)
    , finalized(rhs.finalized)
    , finalizing(rhs.finalizing)
    {
    }

    inline StateMachineFlags& operator=(const StateMachineFlags& rhs)
    {
        initialized = rhs.initialized;
        initializing= rhs.initializing;
        finalized = rhs.finalized;
        finalizing = rhs.finalizing;
        return *this;
    }

    static const StateMachineFlags& Initializing()
    {
        static StateMachineFlags initializingFlags(false,true,false,false);
        return initializingFlags;
    }

    static const StateMachineFlags& Initialized()
    {
        static StateMachineFlags initializedFlags(true,false,false,false);
        return initializedFlags;
    }

    static const StateMachineFlags& Finalizing()
    {
        static StateMachineFlags finalizingFlags(false,false,false,true);
        return finalizingFlags;
    }

    static const StateMachineFlags& Finalized()
    {
        static StateMachineFlags finalizedFlags(false,false,true,false);
        return finalizedFlags;
    }

    static const StateMachineFlags& Empty()
    {
        static StateMachineFlags emptyFlags;
        return emptyFlags;
    }

protected:
    /**
     * Constructor for StateMachineFlags.
     */
    inline StateMachineFlags()
    : initialized(false)
    , initializing(false)
    , finalized(false)
    , finalizing(false)
    {
    }

    inline StateMachineFlags(bool initialized_, bool initializing_, bool finalized_, bool finalizing_)
    : initialized(initialized_)
    , initializing(initializing_)
    , finalized(finalized_)
    , finalizing(finalizing_)
    {
    }

};

/**
 * Represents the base class for a state machine.
 *
 * @tparam StateMachineImpl Specifies the class implementing the state machine.
 * @tparam IState Specifies the internal interface of state implementations for the state
 *                machine.
 */
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    , class StateMachineMutexType = sttcl::internal::SttclMutex<STTCL_DEFAULT_MUTEXIMPL>
#endif
    >
class StateMachine
{

public:
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    typedef StateMachineMutexType MutexType;
#endif
    /**
     * The state machine implementation type.
     */
    typedef StateMachineImpl Context;
    /**
     * The internal state implementation interface.
     */
    typedef IState StateInterface;
    /**
     * The internal state implementation base type.
     */
    typedef StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState> StateBaseClass;

    friend class StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState>;

    /**
     * Destructor for class StateMachine.
     */
    ~StateMachine()
    {
        if(isInitialized() && !isFinalizing() && !isFinalized() && getState())
        {
            finalize();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the state machine.
     * @param force Indicates to finalize the state machine before (re-)initializing.
     * @return The ready state of the state machine.
     */
    bool initialize(bool force = false)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if(force || (!isInitialized() && !isInitializing()) )
        {
            setStateMachineFlags(StateMachineFlags::Initializing());
            result = static_cast<Context*>(this)->initializeImpl(force);
        }
        if(result)
        {
            setStateMachineFlags(StateMachineFlags::Initialized());
            result = isReady();
        }
        else
        {
            setStateMachineFlags(StateMachineFlags::Empty());
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Finalizes the state machine.
     *
     * @param finalizeSubStateMachines Indicates to finalize any sub state machines.
     */
    void finalize(bool finalizeSubStateMachines = true)
    {
        if(!isFinalized() && !isFinalizing())
        {
            setStateMachineFlags(StateMachineFlags::Finalizing());
            static_cast<Context*>(this)->finalizeImpl(finalizeSubStateMachines);
            setStateMachineFlags(StateMachineFlags::Finalized());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is ready to process events.
     * @return \c true if the state machine is ready to process events, \c false otherwise.
     */
    inline bool isReady() const
    {
        return static_cast<const Context*>(this)->isReadyImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for isReady().

     * @return \c true if the state machine is ready to process events, \c false otherwise.
     */
    inline bool isReadyImpl() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,flags.initialized && !flags.finalized);
    }

    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is initialized.
     * @return \c true if the state machine is initialized, \c false otherwise.
     */
    bool isInitialized() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,(flags.initialized && !flags.initializing && !flags.finalizing && !flags.finalized));
    }

    /**
     * Sets the initialized flag of the state machine.
     */
//    void setInitialized(bool value)
//    {
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
//        flags.initialized = value;
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
//    }

    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is currently initializing.
     * @return \c true if the state machine is currently initializing, \c false otherwise.
     */
    bool isInitializing() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,flags.initializing);
    }

    void setStateMachineFlags(const StateMachineFlags& value)
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
        flags = value;
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the initializing flag of the state machine.
     */
//    void setInitializing(bool value)
//    {
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
//        flags.initializing = value;
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
//    }

    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is finalized.
     * @return \c true if the state machine is finalized, \c false otherwise.
     */
    bool isFinalized() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,(flags.finalized && !flags.initializing && !flags.initialized));
    }

    /**
     * Sets the finalized flag of the state machine.
     */
//    void setFinalized(bool value)
//    {
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
//        flags.finalized = value;
//        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
//    }

    /**
     * Indicates that the state machine is currently finalizing.
     * @return \c true if the state machine is currently finalizing, \c false otherwise.
     */
    bool isFinalizing() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,flags.finalizing);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the finalizing flag of the state machine.
     */
    void setFinalizing(bool value)
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
        flags.finalizing = value;
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current state.
     *
     * @return The current state.
     */
    inline StateBaseClass* getState() const
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,state);
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the initialize() method.
     * @param force Indicates to finalize the state machine before (re-)initializing.
     * @return The ready state of the state machine.
     */
    inline bool initializeImpl(bool force)
    {
        if(force)
        {
            StateBaseClass* currentState = getState();
            if(currentState)
            {
                currentState->finalizeSubStateMachines(true);
            }
            if(!isFinalized())
            {
                finalize(true);
            }
        }

        StateBaseClass* initialState = getInitialState();
        if(initialState)
        {
            changeState(initialState);
        }
        StateBaseClass* currentState = getState();
        if(currentState)
        {
            currentState->initSubStateMachines(force);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the finalize() method.
     *
     * @param finalizeSubStateMachines Indicates to finalize any sub state machines.
     */
    inline void finalizeImpl(bool finalizeSubStateMachines)
    {
        if(state)
        {
            if(finalizeSubStateMachines)
            {
                state->finalizeSubStateMachines(true);
            }
            exitCurrentState();
        }
        setState(0);
        pickUpRunningActiveStates();
    }

    /**
     * Called by a contained (composite) state when its sub state machine is completed (finalized).
     * @param state A pointer to the contained (composite) state.
     */
    inline void subStateMachineCompleted(StateBaseClass* state)
    {
        static_cast<StateMachineImpl*>(this)->subStateMachineCompletedImpl(state);
    }

    /**
     * The default implementation of the subStateMachineCompleted method.
     * @param state A pointer to the contained (composite) state.
     */
    inline void subStateMachineCompletedImpl(StateBaseClass* state)
    {
    }

    inline void registerActiveStateRunning(StateBaseClass* state)
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
            if(activeStatesRunning.find(state) == activeStatesRunning.end())
            {
                activeStatesRunning.insert(state);
            }
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    inline void unregisterActiveStateRunning(StateBaseClass* state)
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
            if(activeStatesRunning.find(state) != activeStatesRunning.end())
            {
                activeStatesRunning.erase(state);
            }
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation to set the state machine to \c isReady() conditions.
     */
    virtual void setReady()
    {
        static_cast<StateMachineImpl*>(this)->setReadyImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation to set the state machine to \c isReady() conditions.
     */
    inline void setReadyImpl()
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
            flags.finalized = false;
            flags.initialized = true;
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the initial state of the state machine.
     *
     * @return The initial state of the state machine.
     */
    StateBaseClass* getInitialState() const
    {
        StateBaseClass* result = static_cast<const Context*>(this)->getInitialStateImpl();
#if defined(STTCL_DEBUG) // && defined(STTCL_HAVE_RTTI)
        if(!result)
        {
            std::cerr << "WARNING: " << typeid(static_cast<const Context*>(this)).name() << ".getInitialStateImpl() returned NULL" << std::endl;
        }
#endif
        return result;
    }

protected:
    /**
     * Constructor for class StateMachine.
     */
    StateMachine()
    : state(0)
    , flags(StateMachineFlags::Empty())
    {
    }

    /**
     * Changes the state machines current state.
     *
     * @param newState The new target state.
     */
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    void changeState(typename StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::StateBaseClass* newState);
#else
    void changeState(typename StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::StateBaseClass* newState);
#endif

    /**
     * Sets the state machines current state without calling any state operations.
     * @param newState
     */
    inline void setState(StateBaseClass* newState)
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
            state = newState;
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
    }

    // Default implementations
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Default implementation for getInitialState().
     *
     * @return The initial state of the state machine.
     */
    inline StateBaseClass* getInitialStateImpl() const
    {
        return 0;
    }

    void exitCurrentState();
    void enterNewState();

    void pickUpRunningActiveStates();

protected:
    StateBaseClass* state;

private:
    StateMachineFlags flags;
#if defined(STTCL_USE_STL)
    std::set<StateBaseClass*> activeStatesRunning;
#endif
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    mutable StateMachineMutexType internalLockGuard;
#endif

};

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
template<class StateMachineImpl, class IState, class StateMachineMutexType>
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::changeState(typename StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::StateBaseClass* newState)
#else
template<class StateMachineImpl, class IState>
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::changeState(typename StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::StateBaseClass* newState)
#endif
{
    if(!isFinalizing())
    {
        if(newState)
        {
            if(newState != state)
            {
                exitCurrentState();
                setState(newState);
                enterNewState();
            }
        }
        else // equivalent to finalize
        {
            finalize();
        }
    }
}

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    , class StateMachineMutexType
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::exitCurrentState()
{
    if(state)
    {
        state->endDo(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::Context*>(this));
        state->exit(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::Context*>(this));
    }
}
#else
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::exitCurrentState()
{
    if(state)
    {
        state->endDo(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::Context*>(this));
        state->exit(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::Context*>(this));
    }
}
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    , class StateMachineMutexType
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::enterNewState()
{
    state->entry(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::Context*>(this));
    state->startDo(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::Context*>(this));
}
#else
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::enterNewState()
{
    state->entry(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::Context*>(this));
    state->startDo(static_cast<StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::Context*>(this));
}
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    , class StateMachineMutexType
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,StateMachineMutexType>::pickUpRunningActiveStates()
#else
template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
    >
void StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>::pickUpRunningActiveStates()
#endif
{
    bool allRunningActiveStatesJoined = false;
    do
    {
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
            allRunningActiveStatesJoined = activeStatesRunning.empty();
        STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
        if(!allRunningActiveStatesJoined)
        {
            StateBaseClass* activeStateToJoin = NULL;
            STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard);
                if(!activeStatesRunning.empty())
                {
                    activeStateToJoin = *(activeStatesRunning.begin());
                }
            STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END;
            if(activeStateToJoin)
            {
                activeStateToJoin->joinDoAction(static_cast<Context*>(this));
            }
        }
    } while(!allRunningActiveStatesJoined);
}

}

#endif /* STATEMACHINE_H_ */
```

[**State.h**](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/blob/master/sttcl/include/State.h)

```
/* license header omitted */
#ifndef STATE_H_
#define STATE_H_

#include <SttclConfig.h>

namespace sttcl
{

template
    < class StateMachineImpl
    , class IState
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    , class StateMachineMutexType
#endif
    >
class StateMachine;

/**
 * Represents a particular state machines state base class.
 *
 * @tparam StateMachineImpl The state machine implementation type.
 * @tparam IState Specifies the internal interface of state implementations for the state
 *                machine.
 */
template<class StateMachineImpl,class IState>
class StateBase
: public IState
{
#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
    friend class StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState,typename StateMachineImpl::MutexType>;
#else
    friend class StateMachine<StateMachineImpl,IState>;
#endif

public:
    /**
     * The state machine implementation type.
     */
    typedef StateMachineImpl Context;

    /**
     * The internal state implementation interface.
     */
    typedef IState StateInterface;

    /**
     * Called by the containing StateMachine to finalize any sub state machines.
     * @param recursive If \c true further sub state machines should be finalized
     *                  recursively.
     */
    virtual void finalizeSubStateMachines(bool recursive) = 0;

    /**
     * Called by the containing StateMachine to initialize any sub state machines.
     * @param recursive If \c true further sub state machines should be initialized
     *                  recursively.
     */
    virtual void initSubStateMachines(bool recursive) = 0;

    /**
     * Called by the containing state machine when the state is entered.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    virtual void entry(Context* context) = 0;
    /**
     * Called by the containing state machine when the state is left.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    virtual void exit(Context* context) = 0;
    /**
     * Called by the containing state machine after the state was entered.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    virtual void startDo(Context* context) = 0;
    /**
     * Called by the containing state machine before the state is left.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    virtual void endDo(Context* context) = 0;

    /**
     * Called by the containig state machine to pickup finished asynchronous doAction threads.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    virtual void joinDoAction(Context* context) = 0;

    /**
     * Default implementation for the changeState() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     * @param newState The new sibling state the containing state machine should change to.
     */
    void changeStateImpl(Context* context,StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState>* newState)
    {
        context->changeState(newState);
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the changeState() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     * @param newState The new sibling state the containing state machine should change to.
     */
    template<class StateMachineContext>
    void changeStateImpl(StateMachineContext* context,StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState>* newState)
    {
        context->changeState(newState);
    }
protected:

    /**
     * Constructor for class StateBase.
     */
    StateBase() {}
    /**
     * Destructor for class StateBase.
     */
    virtual ~StateBase() {}

};

/**
 * Represents a particular state machines state implementation base class.
 *
 * @tparam StateImpl The state implementation type.
 * @tparam StateMachine The state machine implementation type.
 * @tparam IState Specifies the internal interface of state implementations for the state
 *                machine.
 */
template<class StateImpl,class StateMachineImpl,class IState>
class State
: public StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState>
{
public:
    /**
     * The state machine implementation type.
     */
    typedef StateMachineImpl Context;

    /**
     * The implementation class type.
     */
    typedef StateImpl Implementation;

    /**
     * The state base class type.
     */
    typedef StateBase<StateMachineImpl,IState> StateBaseType;

    /**
     * The state do action type.
     * The first parameter is a pointer to the containing state machine, the second parameter
     * indicates that the state do action is called the first time when \c true.
     */
    typedef void (Implementation::*StateDoAction)(Context*,bool);

    /**
     * Default implementation for the entry() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    inline void entryImpl(Context* context)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the exit() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    inline void exitImpl(Context* context)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the startDo() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    inline void startDoImpl(Context* context)
    {
        if(doAction)
        {
            (static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->*doAction)(context,true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the endDo() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    inline void endDoImpl(Context* context)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the joinDoAction() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     */
    inline void joinDoActionImpl(Context* context)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the finalizeSubStateMachines() method.
     * @param recursive If \c true further sub state machines should be finalized
     *                  recursively.
     */
    void finalizeSubStateMachinesImpl(bool recursive)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the initSubStateMachines() method.
     * @param recursive If \c true further sub state machines should be initialized
     *                  recursively.
     */
    void initSubStateMachinesImpl(bool recursive)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Default implementation for the getDirectTransitionImpl() method.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     * @param nextState Receives a pointer to the next sibling state to appear on a direct transition.
     * @param finalize Receives \c true to finalize the containing state machine.
     * @return \c true if a direct transition should be performed, \c false otherwise.
     */
    bool checkDirectTransitionImpl(Context* context, bool& finalize, StateBaseType*& nextState)
    {
        nextState = 0;
        finalize = false;
        return false;
    }

protected:
    /**
     * Constructor for class State.
     *
     * @param argDoAction A pointer to the state do action.
     */
    State(StateDoAction argDoAction = 0)
    : doAction(argDoAction)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Destructor for class State.
     */
    virtual ~State()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Changes \em context state machine to another sibling state.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     * @param newState A pointer to the sibling state to change to.
     */
    void changeState(Context* context,StateBaseType* newState)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->changeStateImpl(context,newState);
    }

    /**
     * Changes \em context state machine to another sibling state.
     * @param context A pointer to the containing state machine.
     * @param newState A pointer to the sibling state to change to.
     */
    template<class StateMachineContext>
    void changeState(StateMachineContext* context,StateBaseType* newState)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->changeStateImpl(context,newState);
    }

    /**
     * The state do action.
     */
    StateDoAction doAction;

private:
    virtual void entry(Context* context)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->entryImpl(context);
    }

    virtual void exit(Context* context)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->exitImpl(context);
    }

//    template<class StateMachineContext>
//    virtual void entry(StateMachineContext* context)
//    {
//        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->entryImpl(context);
//    }
//
//    template<class StateMachineContext>
//    virtual void exit(StateMachineContext* context)
//    {
//        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->exitImpl(context);
//    }

    virtual void startDo(Context* context)
    {
        // Run the do action
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->startDoImpl(context);

        // Handle direct transitions
        StateBaseType* nextState = 0;
        bool finalize = false;
        if(static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->checkDirectTransitionImpl(context,finalize,nextState))
        {
            if(finalize)
            {
                context->finalize();
            }
            else if(nextState)
            {
                changeState(context,nextState);
            }
        }
    }

    virtual void endDo(Context* context)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->endDoImpl(context);
    }

    virtual void joinDoAction(Context* context)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->joinDoActionImpl(context);
    }

    virtual void finalizeSubStateMachines(bool recursive)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->finalizeSubStateMachinesImpl(recursive);
    }

    virtual void initSubStateMachines(bool recursive)
    {
        static_cast<Implementation*>(this)->initSubStateMachinesImpl(recursive);
    }

};
}

#endif /* STATE_H_ */
```

[**SttclConfig.h**](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/blob/master/sttcl/include/SttclConfig.h)

```
/*
 * SttclConfig.h
 *
 *  Created on: 13.03.2013
 *      Author: Admin
 */

#ifndef STTCLCONFIG_H_
#define STTCLCONFIG_H_

#define STTCL_USE_STL
#define STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL

#define STTCL_HAVE_RTTI
#define STTCL_HAVE_HIGHRES_CLOCK

#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
#if defined(STTCL_HAVE_HIGHRES_CLOCK)
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
#endif
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_POSIX_IMPL)
#if defined(STTCL_HAVE_HIGHRES_CLOCK)
#define STTCL_POSIX_NANOSLEEP
#endif
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL)
#include "SttclMutex.h"
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL) && !defined(STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN)
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,_ReturnValue_) \
        sttcl::internal::AutoLocker<StateMachineMutexType> lock(internalLockGuard); \
        return (_ReturnValue_);
#else
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFE_RETURN(internalLockGuard,_ReturnValue_)
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL) && !defined(STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START)
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard) \
        { sttcl::internal::AutoLocker<StateMachineMutexType> lock(internalLockGuard);
#else
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_START(internalLockGuard)
#endif

#if defined(STTCL_THREADSAFE_IMPL) && !defined(STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END)
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END \
        }
#else
#define STTCL_STATEMACHINE_SAFESECTION_END
#endif

#endif /* STTCLCONFIG_H_ */
```

For an example of usage refer to [Demo1](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl/tree/master/demo1) please.

---

Proceed to [*Part II: Abstraction of asynchronous/concurrency features*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160465/sttcl-fsm-framework-based-on-the-gof-state-pattern-part-ii-abstraction-of-asyn)